# Combine linux commands into one output

Tags: macos, bash, ubuntu, cat

I cat some files into a markdown parser, and want to pre/ap-pend a head/foot-er. Currently, I do it with a few commands, but would like to do it with a one liner. Here is the command I want to add to...

```
cat  `find .. -name "*.md" -type f` | marked
```

That produces the middle of my document, so I would like to do something like...

```
cat head.template (cat `find ... ` | marked)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try grouping the "source" commands like this:

```
{ cat header_part ; cat `find ...` ; cat footer_part } | marked
```

If you only want the middle part parsed:

```
{ cat header_part ; cat `find ...` | marked ; cat footer_part } > output_file
```

Thanks to [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers), prefer `$()` over backticks:

```
{ cat header_part ; cat $(find ...) | marked ; cat footer_part ) > output_file
```

Comment: Almost, but I only want the middle one to be parsed by marked... maybe I will try moving the grouping braces

Comment: No need for a family of `cat`s: `cat header_part $(find ... | marked) footer_part > output_file`

Comment: @Ansgar: in fact that doesn't do the same thing, will need to keep the family of cats.

Comment: FWIW, `find .. -name '*.md' -type f -exec cat {} +` is going to be

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, a combination of `$( ... commands ... )` and back ticks.

```
echo `cat head.html.snippet`  `cat $(find .. -name "*.md" -type f) | marked` `cat foot.html.snippet` > all.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses less subprocesses and works if the names contain spaces:

`shopt -s globstar; { cat head.html.snippet; cat ../**/*.md | marked; cat foot.html.snippet; } > all.htm`

You could also use process substitution:

`cat head.html.snippet <(find .. -name '*.md' -exec cat {} \+ | marked) foot.html.snippet > all.htm`